# Copying specific data from one MySQL table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, let's call it old and another called new.

I need to select IP's from old (column ip) and insert it into new where the email on each row matches.

ie: there's an email in both tables called email@email.com. The ip in new is empty. I need to get ip from old and insert it into new where the email is the same (email is unique). This should occur for each row.

Is this close?

```
INSERT INTO new (ip)  
SELECT old.ip FROM old  
WHERE new.email = old.email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is so close. Better off use the explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO new (ip)
SELECT old.ip 
FROM old
INNER JOIN new on old.email = new.email;
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) happy I was close! I'll accept the answer when I can in 7 minutes

Comment: @Dave - Good point, I think he is doing something like migration from old tables to new one, may be he inserted other data as well as the `ip`.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: If you're interested in another question of mine to elaborate on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937712/copying-mysql-data-and-creating-a-new-record-with-a-condition