# Copying MySQL data and creating a new record with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Originally I had to get the ip from old table and place it into the new table where the emails match in both.

```
INSERT INTO new (ip)
SELECT old.ip 
FROM old
INNER JOIN new on old.email = new.email;
```

I now need to change this query to do the following:

Get ip from old table
Match it the email from that row in the new table
Get the user_id from new table
Create a record in combined table with user_id and ip

Query so far:

Is this close? Doesn't seem right :/

```
comb_uid = SELECT old.ip FROM old  
WHERE new.email = old.email

comb_ip = SELECT new.user_id FROM new  

INSERT INTO combined (user_id, ip)
VALUES comb_uid, comb_ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were close enough. just change `new` into `combined`.

```
INSERT INTO combined (ip, user_ID)
SELECT  old.ip, new.user_ID
FROM    old
        INNER JOIN new 
            on old.email = new.email;
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
INSERT INTO combined (ip, user_ID, status)
SELECT  old.ip, new.user_ID, 'approved'
FROM    old
        INNER JOIN new 
            on old.email = new.email;
```

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I also wanted to insert a value into another column `status` of "approved". How can I insert "approved" into the `status` column during that `INSERT INTO` for all of these?